# how can I know that the user clicked on the section header in Static TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I need to hide and show section's row ( in which there is a DatePicker). Now for this I'm using buttons which placed in table rows too, but it's bad way. I want that when the user taps on section header - DatePicker row show up, and and tap again - hiding. How can I now when user pressed on section header? Maybe there are another solution for this?

Now it's look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you add button in cell or headerview?

Comment: @mani "Hide", "Show" buttons in cells, How can I add button in headView, in right corner will be great

Comment: Best way to do this, add one custom button on Middle header view, when you click on `Middle` just refresh table view to show corresponding row, otherwise hide it. I think, no need to create extra cell for `show` and `hide` buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Better go with by adding UIButton in header

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
//Within this view you can add a button which is the same size of section height and call create related function when button is clicked

return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom view with tag in viewForHeaderInSection: method:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:....];
    view.tag = section;
    // Customize your view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(headerTapped:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tap]
    return view;
}
```

And in your headerTapped: method you can recognise which view was tapped base on tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a) method of UITableViewDelegate to return a view that have a label (the header name).
Before returning the view, you can add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the header view, that calls some selector when the header view is touched. In that method, you can hide or show the entire section.

Answer (score 0):

You can add button in viewForHeaderInSection. And determine its click event.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {


    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
     UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)];

     // create the button object
     UIButton * headerBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     headerBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     headerBtn.opaque = NO;
     headerBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 320.0);
     [headerBtn setTitle:@"Middle" forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionEventForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [customView addSubview:headerBtn];

     return customView;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is..

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == MIDDLE_SECTION) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
   //Within this view you can add a button which is the same size of section height and call create related function when button is clicked
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   button.frame = view.frame;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(middleSectionPressed:)          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return view;

}
return nil;
}

-(void)middleSectionPressed:(id)sender
{

    if (self.isMiddleSelected)
    {
     self.isMiddleSelected = YES;
       }
    else 
       self.isMiddleSelected = NO
   [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:middleIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

Now load section cell according to this middleSelected boolean.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == MIDDLE_SECTION)
    {
       if (self.isMiddleSelected)
         return 1;
      else 
     return 0;
   }
}
```